# java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.profile.model.Profile - Spring Boot

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, hashmap

I have a microservice architecture where I am trying to call other service via `exchange` method to get list of users profiles.

```
@Override
    public List<Profile> getListOfProfile(List<String> receiverId) {
        ListOfProfileDto listOfProfileDto = new ListOfProfileDto();
        listOfProfileDto.setId(receiverId);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<Object> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(listOfProfileDto, httpHeaders);
        try {
            Object foundProfile = restTemplate.exchange(
                    "http://localhost:8087/profile-service/profile/list",
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    requestEntity,
                    Object.class
            ).getBody();
            return (List<Profile>) foundProfile;

        } 
    }
```

When I get that list in other part of code I am trying to iterate it.

```
  receiversProfiles.forEach(rp -> {
            var invitedFriend = InvitedFriends.builder()
                    .firstName(rp.getFirstName())
                    .lastName(rp.getLastName())
                    .build();
            invitedFriendsList.add(invitedFriend);
        });
```

And here is where I am getting following error:

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "timeStamp": "15/05/2022 15:35:27",
    "message": "class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.profile.model.Profile (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.profile.model.Profile is in unnamed module of loader 'app')",
    "details": "uri=/profile/save"
}
```

When I am getting response from my other service I am seeing this:

[image]

Where found profile is a `hashmap` that I am trying to convert to `List<Profile>`
but not able to.

and in this piece of code when I am trying to iterate

```
receiversProfiles.forEach(rp -> {
            var invitedFriend = InvitedFriends.builder()
                    .firstName(rp.getFirstName())
                    .lastName(rp.getLastName())
                    .build();
            invitedFriendsList.add(invitedFriend);
        });
```

I guess I am trying to iterate trough hashmap as I am iterating trough list and this is why my code is braking.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
 List<Profile> foundProfile = restTemplate.exchange(
              "http://localhost:8087/profile-service/profile/list",
               HttpMethod.POST,
               requestEntity,
               new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Profile>>() {}
).getBody();
```

Try this to cast to List of `Profile` upon executing request.

Comment: new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Profile>>() {}

Answer (score 1):

When Jackson attempts to deserialize an object in JSON, but no target type information is given, it'll use the default type: LinkedHashMap.

[Jackson: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to X](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast)